# Philips 237E disable bootup logo

Tags: display, lcd, firmware

Every time I boot up a Philips 237E LCD, the screen shows the Philips logo on a bright blue background, which I find jarring.

I know that on different models this can be disabled by [entering the Service Menu](https://factory-reset.com/wiki/Philips_Service_Menu) via the buttons, but this model has a "joystick" instead of buttons, and I can't hold multiple ones pressed at the same time (to attempt to reproduce the old key sequence).

**Is there a way to disable the logo shown on startup?**

I boot it up every day, because I sleep in the same room, and the LED is blinking white when it's on standby (another firmware annoyance). I tried covering the LED, but the case plastic still scatters the blinking light.

Comment: What does the owners manual say?

Comment: @Moab Owner's manual says nothing about the logo.

Comment: Then there is nothing you can do.